# How to extract string between two pattern using sed in Linux while second pattern repeating more lines in file

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed

E.g.

```
xyz
A1
B1
C1
D1
End
End
End
X1
X2
X3
Done
```

I want to extract all string between xyz to End pattern. So output should be

```
xyz
A1
B1
C1
D1
End
End
End
```

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: Note that here, the **last** occurrence of the second pattern ends the block, not the first one.

Answer (score 1):

### Method-a

```
perl -l -0777ne 'print /^(xyz.*?^End$(?:\nEnd$)*)/ms' yourfile
```

### Working

- Slurp the file so that it appears as a looooong string which can then be taken apart using the appropriate regex. The regex in this case is:

  - look for xyz at the start of a line (not necessarily the file).
  - look for the nearest End on a line by itself and then as many such consecutive lines.

### Method-2

```
perl -lne '
   next unless /xyz/ ... eof;
   last if !/End/ and $flag;
   $flag ||= 1 if /End/;
   print;
' yourfile
```

### Working

- Here we operate Perl on a per-line basis and setup a small state machine.

  - Reject any non-range portion of the file.
  - Once we enter the right range, we print all lines till we hit the /End/ line. At that point we set the flag.
  - Then we break out as soon as we see the first non /End/ line.

### Method-3

```
sed -e '
   /xyz/!d
   :a
      $q;N
   /\nEnd$/!ba
   :b
      n
   /End/bb
   d
' yourfile
```

In this method we operate the first do-while loop (:a) which will accumulate lines starting from /xyz/ to /End/.

The second do-while loop (:b) will print lines till the next line happens to be /End/.

### Method-4

```
sed -e '
   /xyz/,/End/!d
   H;/xyz/h;/End/!d
   :a
      $q;N
      /\(.*\)\n\1$/!{g;q;}
      s/.*\n//;H
   ba
' yourfile
```

With this method we are first selecting the right range then storing that range data in the hold space. The do-while loop (:a) is setup which incrementally appends to the hold space while the next line happens to be /End/.

### Results

```
xyz
A1
B1
C1
D1
End
End
End
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl to the rescue: Print all the lines between the first `xyz` and the last `End`:

```
 perl -ne '
     $inside = 1        if /^xyz$/;
     $seen_end = 1      if $inside && /^End$/;
     push @buff, $_     if $inside;
     print splice @buff if /^End$/ && @buff;
' input-file
```

From the first occurrence of `xyz`, we start pushing all lines into a buffer. Once `End` is encountered, we output and clear the buffer (see [splice](http://p3rl.org/splice)), but we continue to push lines into the buffer in case there was another `End` later.

Answer (score 0):

This is a kind of job `pcregrep` is good at:

```
pcregrep -M 'xyz(.|\n)*End' file
```

Notice that it is very greedy and eats everything till the final *End*, including other *End*s.

Answer (score 0):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk '/xyz/,/End/{ print $0; n=NR }($0=="End" && n && NR>n && NR-n++ == 1)' file
```

The output:

```
xyz
A1
B1
C1
D1
End
End
End
```

---

- `/xyz/,/End/` - record range, from `xyz` to `End`
- `n=NR` - capturing record number (on range matching - will eventually contain the number of the last record of the range)

Answer (score 0):

As you are asking for an `sed` solution, I'd do it like this:

```
sed -e '/^xyz$/!d;:a' -e '$!{N;ba' -e '};s/\(.*\nEnd\).*/\1/'
```

So discard everything before the first pattern (`/^xyz$/!d`), then loop to collect all remaining lines in the pattern space (`:a;$!{N;ba`) and remove everything behind the last occurence of the second pattern (`s/\(.*\nEnd\).*/\1/`).

Collecting in the pattern space is neccessary as addressing (`/xyz/,/End/`) is not greedy, but `.*` inside the pattern space is.